# jQuery UI autocomplete works in weird way

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I want to use "auto-complete" in one of my input field.

Function:

```
$("input[data-autocomplete]").each(function() {
    $(this).autocomplete({ source: $(this).attr("data-autocomplete")
    });
```

And piece of html (input which should be autocompleted):

```
<input data-autocomplete="@Url.Action("GetTagsByName","Ideas")" 
   id="tags" name="tags" type="text" value="Add tags separated by commas"/>
```

And it works-almost. List of tags shows but not in normal "autocompleting" way but as:

```
<a class="ui-corner-all ui-state-hover" tabindex="-1" 
        id="ui-active-menuitem">aaa</a>
```

in bottom on the screen. Im not expert in jQuery UI,anyone knows what i do wrong?

Comment: Looks like a styling problem. Does your page include one of the jQuery UI CSS theme files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was quite simple-i had mess in my css files.